# X Server implementation vs Linux distributions

Tags: x11, distributions, x-server

Linux has a lot of distribution - [here](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity) is the popularity ranking. Do all Linux distributions share the same X Server implementation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course nobody can know all X server implementations nor all Linux distros. There will be distros for specific use cases and they will ship legacy software, because of some specific reason.

But to the best of my knowledge, there is only one fully-featured standalone open source X Server implementation that targets Linux and still is being supported, the X.org Server, and so every Foss Linux distro that tries to support X natively will have to ship exactly that.

Not that not every Linux distro has to support X natively. With Wayland, there is at least a partially viable alternative to X (and with XWayland you could even run X applications; but XWayland is also part of the X.org Server, so that's also the same server). It is generally hoped that Wayland ecosystem reaches maturity, and that Wayland replaces the X protocol and architecture one day, getting rid of 40 years of questionable design decisions.

Comment: And the X.org developers have mostly switched to working on Wayland components, so from a community perspective there’s lots of overlap between X.org and Wayland.

Comment: For now it seems we are stuck with the X/Wayland dichotomy as Wayland brings its own questionable design decisions, many of which are no better than X's.

Comment: @user253751 yes, but that's evoking a false balance. Just as we're stuck between steam engines and 4-stroke engines, and both have their downsides and kinks, but one is clearly technologically superior, even if it has problems the other doesn't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wayland is not clearly technologically superior. It might look that way in the marketing, but when you delve a little bit deeper, it isn't. It's just technologically different in ways that certain influential people happen to like.

Comment: @user253751 sorry. I know sufficiently well from working on direct memory access and on patching DRM drivers to get freaking acceleration to work on X.org how bad the X architecture works for that. Wayland *is* technologically superior. Not surprising - it's literally decades less of cruft. Sorry to shatter your conspiracy theory, but: it's not "influential people". It's basically *everybody who's formerly been working on X.org* that's now working on Wayland. Not because of "powerful people", but because X in 2023 is simply a technological deadend, and people who know graphics systems know.

Comment: @user253751 you'll also have to realize that fewer and fewer people will feel the need to support the legacy X.org nightmare. For example, Asahi Linux, the FOSS endeavour to support Apple M1 / M2 computers, has heavy work on supporting the GPU in these computers. These are people who aren't paid by anyone and don't need to listen to any "influential people". You know what they do? They simply say "it's nice if you want to use X, but you'll have to fix that on your own – we work on making things run smooth on Wayland". And these aren't newbs; it's the same authors as the panfrost/bifrost

Comment: … Gallium MESA driver backends. So, your claim that it's a marketing claim is just FUD. By now, Wayland can do several things that are architecturally impossible with X, and it's utterly clear that the days of X are more than counted. Every major Linux distro supports Wayland – many already default to it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Other people say "it's nice if you want to use Wayland, but you'll have to fix that on your own - we work on making things run smooth on X." As I said, it's different. Some driver developers might prefer Wayland because it makes drivers deal with less application BS - but X makes applications deal with less driver/platform BS (despite the promises of Wayland). The Linux world will probably reach equilibrium, like with GNOME/KDE.

Comment: A straightforward example of Wayland BS is that it's very difficult to take screenshots. It turns out that people want to take screenshots. In X you can just ask for the pixels currently on the screen, and get them. IIRC it's also difficult to make screensavers or MSN-like notification boxes. This is all to do with the opinionated application-side API of Wayland - I've no doubt the driver side removes cruft because it's a mess in X. But Wayland needs to be good on *both* sides to actually replace X, otherwise we'll get a mishmash depending on which side each person finds more important.

Comment: (another advantage of Wayland is on unconventional devices like mobile phones. Because it doesn't give the application much more control than "here's some pixel data, please render it", it allows for much more flexibility in compositors, including ones with Android-style task switchers for example. But this is dampened by the opinionated insistence on client-side decorations meaning all the apps in your Android-style compositor will still have desktop-style window decorations!!!)

Answer (score 2):

[Tiny Core Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Core_Linux), a Linux distribution that focus on being as lightweight as possible, uses its own fork of Xvesa, an old minimal alternative X implementation, called [TinyX](https://github.com/tinycorelinux/tinyx). It might not support all of X.org features, but it worked well when I used Tiny Core. You have to sacrifice some things to make a modern Linux distribution that fits on 11 MB of disk and that only requires 50 MB of RAM.

So, yes, it's official, not all Linux distro ships with the X.org version of X11.

I'm also going to add that OpenBSD use its own fork of X.org called [Xenocara](https://xenocara.org/). I don't believe they change much other than what they need to make it compile, so not really a different version than the X.org everyone else uses.

Comment: how cool is that :) Yes! when performance and modern feature-completeness isn't your primary goal, but being able to build an absurdly compact system: what a nice thing!